# What is the role of arg in variable argument function defined as int function(int arg, ...)?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I am learning about variable argument functions in C and i came across different codes which uses different named argument (injector message as per some websites). `int function(int count, ...)`, `int function(char *string, ...)`.I tried running below code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>

int addition(int count, ...)
{
    va_list values;
    va_start(values, count);

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count + 2; i++)
    {
        sum += va_arg(values, int);
    }

    return sum;
}

int main(void)
{
    int sum = average(3,12,23,43,65,12);

    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

It ran successfully again. By writing above code i have no intention to get the addition but just to understand the role of named argument(count) there are few points which made me skeptical.

I thought named argument is the number of arguments passed to the variadic function. But after encountring a function `int function(char *string, ...)` and using above code i am clear this isn't its role.

In above function i can pass count+2 in for loop to find the sum, and i can get the same result as intended, So clearly importance of named argument depends on functionality of the code.

There are many instances one wants to pass a variable count to a variadic function like taking average or passing a char* to create a input function like scanf. But on the same place there can be some cases where there is no need of any named argument (i don't know any example but i believe there may be some cases)

I thought the reason to use a named argument may lie in the inability of a compilor to figure out if the argument passed is named argument or not. But by removing named argument in average function `int average(...)`, i am getting compiler error that there is no named argument passed. So compiler can distinguish between a named argument and a variable argument. This can also be illustrated by changing the declaration of the addition function to `int addition(int count, int another, ...)`, by doing this compiler will give error that int count is not the last named argument.

The only thing i don't understand is this, why named argument is necessary even though it is not necessarily going to affect the working of the program (as per my knowledge). As compiler can distinguish between a named argument and a variable argument, one can use this ability to create a function which takes only variable arguments and a variadic function with named argument at the same time.

va_start is taking named argument as 2nd argument and on [this website](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_start/?kw=va_start) it states  `void va_start (va_list ap, paramN); Initializes ap to retrieve the additional arguments after parameter paramN.` As i understand this, it means that 2nd argument is to tell compiler that arguments after paramN are variable arguments, But i think compiler already knows which argument is which.

Comment: The role can be anything you want. In `printf()` it's the format string, and it derives the number of additional arguments from the number of `%` operations in the string.

Comment: First time I hear the term "injector message" in this context. Also couldn't find any resource using it. So you probably shouldn't as well.

Comment: `va_start()` needs an argument name to link it to the argument list.

Comment: @Barmar yes but that list is values here, than what is the role of 2nd argument in va_start i.e. count here

Comment: @EugeneSh. I saw a website using it and i thought this is the actual term for it So i used it here

Comment: @tycoon That's what I was talking about. It's the variable in the parameter list that tells `va_start()` where the variable arguments come from.

Comment: @Barmar ohh sorry i misunderstood. But the question i have in my head is that if compiler can distinguish between a variable argument and a named argument than why it want us to pass it that value.

Comment: The reason is almost certainly historic, from before `...` was added to the language. It was a macro that used `&paramN` to find the location in the stack frame of the additional arguments.